# Symfony 4 doctrine creating issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine, ubuntu-16.04, symfony-4.2

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and when trying to create schema (bin/console doctrine:schema:create) get a lot of errors

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you configured your db connection correctly?

Comment: From error it is clear that drivers not found. Please install pdo and mysql driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the driver pdo_mysql.

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql`